# Is there way to not replace existing MPC-playlist when double click media file?

Tags: media-player, media-player-classic

So my problem is that I have some pre-made playlist and when i open any media file this playlist is overwrite with new one that contain only this file.
It is possible to add file that I opened at the end of current playlist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch it with the `/add` switch

If using windows to can edit this in under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mplayerc.avi\shell\open\command`

!!! Do not directly edit your registries unless you know what you're messing with. If you do, always make a backup first.

Answer (score 0):

I know of two options.

1. Drag the file into the playlist. It will then appear in it without replacing the playlist.
2. Disable the option that restricts MPC to a single instance. Files you click on will then appear in a new instance of MPC with its own playlist box.

Perhaps there is a way to do what you ask but I do not know it.

Comment: This options can be used as workaround but not a solution.Thank you anyway.

Comment: Option 2 only works if you have an instance open (you can close MPC and it will restore the playlist after).